# Runnig curl inside a shell script gives a curl: (6) Could not resolve host: error

Tags: shell-script, centos, curl

when I run this command it works fine:

```
# curl  https://google.com
```

output:

```
<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>301 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>301 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="https://www.google.com/">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
```

but when I do the same inside a shell script .sh file:

```
#!/bin/bash

curl  https://google.com
```

output:

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: google.com; Unknown error
```

output of `grep curl /home/pmm/deploy-vsf/test_bot.sh | od -c`:

```
[root@host ~]# grep curl /home/pmm/deploy-vsf/test_bot.sh | od -c
0000000   c   u   r   l           h   t   t   p   s   :   /   /   g   o
0000020   o   g   l   e   .   c   o   m  \n
0000031
```

note: script is being run as `su` but script lives inside home of `pmm` user

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us the actual script, or at least the minimal part of it that reproduces the issue. Is it possible that you have ever edited this script on a Windows machine? What is the output of `grep curl script.sh | od -c`?

Comment: You're running the script on the same machine as the `curl` that works?

Comment: @roaima correct it's on the same machine

Comment: What is output of `type curl` please?

Comment: @roaima the output of `type curl` is:
[root@host~]# type curl
curl is aliased to `curl -x http://192.168.188.170:3128'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your interactive shell [is using an alias](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/724496/runnig-curl-inside-a-shell-script-gives-a-curl-6-could-not-resolve-host-erro/724528#comment1373587_724496) for `curl` that tells it to use a specific web proxy:

```
type curl
curl is aliased to `curl -x 192.168.188.170:3128'
```

When you run a script, aliases are not included (they are intended mainly for interactive use) so you need to specify the missing parts yourself.

```
#!/bin/bash
curl -x 192.168.188.170:3128 https://google.com
```

A better solution might be to set the environment variable `http_proxy` instead of aliasing `curl`. This will work with almost all web tools (but also not across `su` or `sudo` unless the target user also defines it):

```
export http_proxy=192.168.188.170:3128
```